# Is it possible to change the e-mail header before it is processed by MS Exchange 365?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, email, microsoft-exchange

We currently have the following problem with a customer:
The customer uses Microsoft Exchange 365 and has a collective mailbox there where all e-mails end up. Instead of having their own mailbox, each user only has a mail alias and the e-mails are redirected to the collective mailbox.
With TO and CC this works and there are no problems.
At BCC, however, this construct reaches its limits.
Exchange removes the "for" part in the "received" header. This means that emails can no longer be assigned to the original recipient.
[image]

We pick up the emails from the Exchange via the Graph API in order to integrate them into the workflow of our own software.

Is there a way, e.g. using an Exchange plugin, to read the header and write the e-mail address from the "for" part in an x-property before the e-mail is processed by Exchange?

Comment: I really doubt that, as what you see above is "by design" behavior. I would suggest don't play with existing properties. Rather you can try this and i believe it will work - stamp a custom MAPI property/extendedproperty as part of the message, using your application you can read it and implement your business logic (say, you can route to original recipient).

Comment: @Dev: I'm not sure if I got you right but how can I add custom properties to an incoming e-mail before it is processed by exchange? Is there any way to do that? That would solve our problem I guess. Because when we are receiving the e-mails with our software from exchange, the information we need is not in the header any more :(

Comment: Create a [custom extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) or [OpenTypeExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) when you create/send the message, so it will be embedded part of the message properties...

Comment: I know how to add custom properties when sending a message. But I need to do this when RECEIVING a message BEFORE exchange removes information from the message header. But I don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: Oops, i don't think so; thats the reason i suggested to stamp when you send the message itself or create an outlook webaddin which does this for you/your customers. Unfortunately you can't put in Exchange online.

Comment: hm, I was afraid of that answer. The solution for adding properties when sending emails would work when the messages are sent from our software. But when we are receiving messages sent from Outlook, Google, Apple ... I can't add any custom properties. Too bad, it seems we need to search for another solution.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But as i said you can consider creating Outlook webaddins (to stamp the properties) using Office.js, so that you can deploy in Outlook for windows, android and mac. Thats the closest one i see.

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: Sorry, Christmas holidays :)
Unfortunately the webaddins do not help as they only work on the client side. Our customers use Exchange 365 but not the web outlook client. Are such addins also possible on the server side? That would help a lot.

Comment: Happy holidays. I think i updated above, you can't do from server side - its in cloud, where in you can do something if its in on-premise (Say, Exchange On-Prem server).